# Determine which node is raising a ROS error

Tags: ros, orocos, logger, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Orocos with RTT-ROS integration for real-time control, and in the Orocos deployer I keep getting ROS errors like

```
[ERROR] [1529525996.660179901]: Unable to remove FD to epoll: Bad file descriptor
[ERROR] [1529525996.660213076]: Error closing socket [20]: [Bad file descriptor]
```

It comes up intermittently, and I want to know what node is giving that error so I can try to debug what's going on. Is there a way I can identify where the error is originating from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294775/determine-which-node-is-raising-a-ros-error/) by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 642 on 2018-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What I usually do is set [console output formatting](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting) as described in answer [258929](https://answers.ros.org/question/258929/ros-logging-display-node-name/). That will print the node name as part of the error messages.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-21**:
@aconkey: I would recommend looking into what @Thomas D describes here. It'll be much more straightforward.

**Comment by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) on 2018-06-21**:
That's great, I didn't know about this, thanks! Do you know if there's a way you can also format the time differently to be more compact? It takes up a lot of space and for console purposes I don't usually need that precise time tracking.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-06-21**:
I do not see any options in the documentation for truncating the time field.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up figuring out one way just after posting this, but I'll be interested to know if there are other ways. The ROS log file associated with the session includes more information about where the log statement was issued, for example in my case the corresponding entry was

```
e668a370-7434-11e8-a202-f4f26d03b40d/rosout.log:1529464055.546618984 ERROR [/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-roscpp-1.12.13/src/libros/io.cpp:139(del_socket_from_watcher) [topics: /rosout, /lbr4/joint_states, /lbr4/pose] Unable to remove FD to epoll: No such file or directory
```

It actually shows exactly where the error was raised down to the line number, very helpful. I found this by navigating to the ROS log directory (in my case `~/.ros/log`), and doing `grep -r epoll`, if you have the hash for your ROS session you can go directly to that, or do a more advanced `grep` if your error doesn't have identifying keywords.

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlessandroSaviolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/52672/alessandrosaviolo/) on 2020-03-21**:
Thanks! Solved my problem